# How to Rebase on Git when branch on Github says Everything up-to-date

Tags: git, github

I have a PR branch and I rebased it off of master. 
When I do the following:

```
git checkout master
git pull

git checkout featurebranch
git pull
git rebase master
```

I get:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

But on gitHub I get:

```
Rebasing the commits of this branch on top of the base branch cannot be performed automatically due to conflicts encountered while reapplying the individual commits from the head branch.
```

I think i may have done a git rebase --skip on some commits. How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "on git i get" - on github?

Comment: @zrrbite crap sorry I meant github

Comment: What did you expect would happen? That everything is up to date or a conflicted state? Is your git bash or github correct? (E.g. does master contain commits that are not on featurebranch)

Comment: usually when i perform a rebase, gitHub will not raise an error. i'm at a state where github is requesting me to rebase but when I attempt to perform one it says everything is up to date, so I;m not sure what to do

Comment: If you run something like gitk --all locally, what does it tell you? It must tell you that you're either on the same commit as master, or ahead.  And now what does a comparison of the two branches on github tell you?

Comment: looks like you did not `push`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
git checkout featurebranch
git pull
git rebase origin/master
git push -f
```

Comment: when i do that is says Everything up-to-date